# get array of attribute from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Say i have an array of objects in javascript as

```
var array=[{id:1,message:"hello",time:"00-00-0000"},{id:2,message:"sup",time:"00-00-0000"},...];
```

What is the best way to get an array only containing the message attribute. i.e.

```
var messages=["hello","sup",...];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "best" way would be:

```
var messages = array.map(function(x) {return x.message;});
```

The *most compatible* way:

```
for(var messages=[],i=0,l=array.length; i<l; i++) messages[i]=array[i].message;
```

Comment: I never heard of the map function. Nice touch!

Comment: so i guess the only way to do this is to iterate through all objects, i was trying to find something better than that

Comment: If you wanted to know the first or last word of every chapter in a book, you would have to do the same thing, go to each chapter and read the first or last word. How else would you do it?

Comment: @naveed why point at documents for jQuery when this was clearly an ECMA5 method? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @Xotic750 Sorry but I'm new to javascript and having only worked in c/c++, i thought it was possible because all you have to do is iterate through sizeof(object), like if your first string (char array with a fixed size in C) is at memory offset 10 and the sizeof the object is 100, then the second string will be at the offset 110, and the third at 210, but as the string over here has a dynamic size, so i guess that's not possible.

Comment: @stranded You are still iterating over the items in c/c++, just with haxy memory scanning instead of dynamic array iteration.

Comment: No need to be sorry ;) But you would still be iterating in C/C++ (which even `map` is doing behind the scenes), it's the same concept.

Comment: but it's faster and more efficient, over here we're loading the whole object first and then selecting one attribute from it, we wouldn't have to make a new array and waste memory for that.

Comment: C/C++ is more "efficient", so to speak, but it's the same algorithm in both environments. Loop, locate, record, return Or if not recording it, then do something with it, in which case you would possibly use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Comment: You're not loading the whole object, you're just pointing at each object in turn to get a property from it.

Comment: Xotic750, "map was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition; as such it may not be present in all implementations of the standard.", I just provided the link for those implementations of standard, that do not support map function.

Comment: @naveed So you'd rather import an entire library just for one function that I was able to shim in a single line of code? .. Huh.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, Jquery is a widely used library, so it is often present when someone is doing javascript. I just pointed it out for those who are unaware of it. If you only need this function, then obviously adding it to prototype makes much sense.

Comment: @naveed Be that as it may, assuming people use jQuery is like assuming people use Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
var messages = [];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    messages.push(array[i][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A terser, more modern variant on @Niet the Dark Absol's solution is:

```js
const messages = array.map(x => x.message);
```